# Convert a string to a float with support for different locales (English and French)?

Tags: php, localization, number-formatting

Let's say I have these similar numbers in 2 different notations, english and french

> 1,200.25 = english
>
> 1 200,25 = french

Is there a PHP function that can accept any of the 2 numbers and convert them to float?

> 1200.25 = float

Comment: Is there any way to know which locale the input is associated with?

Comment: Can just use `if ($french) { doFrenchConversion() } else { doEnglishOrInvariantConversion() }`? Locales are fairly tricky (even within a locale there can be a good bit of variation).

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
$replacements = array("1,200.25","1 200,25");
foreach($replacements AS $replaceText):
    $replace = preg_replace("#^(.*)(?:\.|\,)([0-9]{1,})$#","$1.$2",$replaceText);
    $replaceChars = array("# #","#,#");
    $text = preg_replace($replaceChars, "", $replace);
    echo $replaceText. " got replaced by: ".$text."<br />";
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
<?php

function parse_float_locale($float_string, $locale) {
    $locale_info = array();
    switch ($locale) {
        case 'fr':
            $locale_info['thousands_sep'] = ' ';
            $locale_info['decimal_point'] = ',';
            break;
        case 'en':
        default:
            $locale_info['thousands_sep'] = ',';
            $locale_info['decimal_point'] = '.';
    }

    $float_string = str_replace($locale_info['thousands_sep'], '', $float_string);
    $float_string = str_replace($locale_info['decimal_point'], '.', $float_string);

    return floatval($float_string);
}

$str_en = '1,200.25';
$str_fr = '1 200,25';

$number_en = parse_float_locale($str_en, 'en');
$number_fr = parse_float_locale($str_fr, 'fr');

echo "Value en: $number_en";
echo "Value fr: $number_fr";
```

This will print:

Value en: 1200.25

Value fr: 1200.25

Comment: You only say "decimal point" because on the English notation you are used to, the *decimal separation* is indeed a point. Thus, this nomenclature used here is misleading, treating one as a separation mark and the other as a "should be point".